# Change IdentityProvider google options on runtime

Tags: identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 to create my company IDP and configured google as a possible external login.

My problem is that the IDP will be integrated with different apps, so what I’m trying to accomplish is to use different Google [ClientId, ClientSecret] based on the client is calling the IDP. (Trying to do this so google authorization will show app specific information and not a general one.)

Is this something possible in IdentityServer4?

GoogleAuthentication configuration is defined at startup and accept only one clientId and clientSecret so I’m not sure if google authentication options can be changed somehow later on runtime.

Thanks!
Andres

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach would be rather to have multiple Google providers registered (each with their own scheme and callback path) - and then based on the incoming client, challenge the associated Google provider.